# How to add extra item at the bottom of the drawer navigation manually (like logout button)?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I want to add logout button to the bottom of the drawer navigation in my RN app.

[image: As you can see the Logout button is located at the bottom of the drawer menu. How can I move it to the bottom of the drawer panel?]

I am trying to use `contentComponent` the following way:

```
const DrawerWithLogoutButton = (props) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </SafeAreaView>
    <Button
      style={styles.logoutButton}
      title="Logout"
      onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Login') }/>
  </ScrollView>
);

export default Home = createDrawerNavigator({
  // screens
}, {
  // other settings
  contentComponent: DrawerWithLogoutButton,
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  logoutButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

In the result I have the Logout button at the bottom of the menu. But I want it to be located at the bottom of the drawer panel instead

Also I would want the Logout button to look like other menu items and had an icon

Is there a way to create drawer navigator with a menu item which has no screen but is just an action like Logout as in my case?

Comment: You should just set ScrollView flex: 1

Comment: @RomanOsypov thank you. I've tried to add `style={{flex: 1}}` to `ScrollView` but it didn't work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to align Logout at the bottom of the drawer menu with adding `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to the `ScrollView` container. You can see the result in the picture

[image: the Logout button is located at the bottom of the drawer menu]

The result source code looks the following way:

```
const DrawerWithLogoutButton = (props) => (
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1,  flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
    <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </SafeAreaView>
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
          <Image source={require('./img/logout.png')} style={styles.icon}></Image>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.label}>Logout</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </ScrollView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  label: {
    margin: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)',
  },
  iconContainer: {
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    width: 24,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

[React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/) recommend wrapping the drawer navigation with a custom content drawer function. This is what we do did to give our drawer a logout button, but also keep all of the `Drawer.Screen`s in place.

In the code below we create a `CustomDrawerContent` that contains a `DrawerItem` as our **logout** button. This function wraps the `Drawer.Navigator` through its property `drawerContent`. Our final drawer then looks like:

- Home (Drawer.Screen)
- Edit Profile (Drawer.Screen)
- Landing (Drawer.Screen)
- Logout (DrawerItem)

```js
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      <DrawerItem label={() => <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Logout</Text>}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} 
        onPress={() => alert('Logged out')}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar translucent={true} />
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Edit Profile' component={EditProfile} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Landing' component={Landing} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to William Griffins answer, except their answer does not end up with the logout button at the bottom of the drawer. To have logout be at the bottom, I put my DrawerContentScrollView inside a SafeAreaView, then beneath the DrawerContentScrollView I put a regular View containing the DrawerItem, which is the logout button.

```js
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{top: "always", horizontal: "never"}}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <DrawerItemList {...props} />
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
            <View>
                <DrawerItem label={"Logout"}
                            style={styles.logoutDrawerItem}
                            onPress={() => console.log('Logout pressed!')}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar translucent={true} />
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Edit Profile' component={EditProfile} />
            <Drawer.Screen name='Landing' component={Landing} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </View>
    </Provider>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logoutDrawerItem: {
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
});
```

Any items you place beneath the DrawerContentScrollView will be placed at the bottom of the drawer.

Note that I set borderRadius to 5 on the logout DrawerItem, so that it closely matches the border radius of regular drawer items.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `position:'absolute'` and `buttom:0` like this code:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => {this.logout()}}
    style={{ bottom: 0, position: 'absolute', width: '100%' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection:'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Icon name="md-log-out" style={{marginRight: 10, color: '#444'}} size={20}/>
        <Text style={{color: '#444'}}>Logout</Text>
      </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You can change the style to make it like other buttons. I hope this will help you...

Comment: thank you for the help! I've tried your answer but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work out for me directly. I had to do some modifications, but in general the secret is indeed using `justifyContent: 'space-between'`.

```
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerContentComponentProps,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function CustomDrawerContent(props: DrawerContentComponentProps) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView
      {...props}
      contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      </View>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Logout"
        onPress={() => console.log('Logged out')}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

.
.
.

        <Drawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
          drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
          drawerContentOptions={{
            activeTintColor: color.primaryDark,
            itemStyle: {
              backgroundColor: 'transperant',
              borderColor: color.primaryDark,
              borderBottomWidth: 1,
              opacity: 0.8,
            },
          }}
          drawerStyle={styles.drawer}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
```